# AngularJS: ui-router login app

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I am creating one simple login app. It should work like in home page it is having two links: login and about, for login I have written the code but now have got stuck and don't know what to do next. Please, someone, guide me. Here is the code:

index.html:

```
<html ng-app="LoginApp">

<head>
    <title>Login App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="login.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="login.state.js"></script>
    <script src="login.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="login.html"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>My Login App</h1> <a ui-sref="login">Login</a> <a ui-sref="about">About</a>
    <div ng-view> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

login.state.js:

```
var app = angular.module("LoginApp", ['ui.router']);
app.config('$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    $stateProvider.state('login', {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "login.html",
        controller: "login.controller.js"
    })
})
```

After successful login, dashboard page should be opened and in failure case again it should be redirected to the login page with error message.Please, someone help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like: `My project doesn't work, what should I do`. Please post specific problem with relevant code or post demo in plunker that demonstrates your issue with routing

Comment: You should ui-view instead of ng-view